# Reading text from image with Pytesseract does not work

Tags: python, opencv, python-tesseract

I want to read letters and numbers from image of licence plates. Im using `Python`, and I have read that I can do this with `pytesseract`.

I wrote a simple code but I got en error:

```
    raise TesseractNotFoundError()
pytesseract.pytesseract.TesseractNotFoundError: tesseract is not installed or it's not in your path
```

I do not know how to fix this, this is my code:

```
import cv2
import pytesseract

img = cv2.imread('image.jpg')
cv2.imshow('original', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)

text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img, config='')
print("Detected Number is:", text)
```

And this is the image:

[image: pyte]

I have already installed pytesseract.
When I run this:

```
import importlib.util
print(importlib.util.find_spec('pytesseract'))
```

I get this:

```
ModuleSpec(name='pytesseract', loader=<_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x02F8F070>, origin='C:\\Users\\Pc\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32\\lib\\site-packages\\pytesseract\\__init__.py', submodule_search_locations=['C:\\Users\\Pc\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32\\lib\\site-packages\\pytesseract'])
```

Comment: Do a `pip install pytesseract`

Comment: I have already done that

Comment: Are you on a windows machine?

Comment: Yes, I have updated the question, please check it

Comment: Try adding the path for tesseract like this, `pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'<full_path_to_your_tesseract_executable>'`

Comment: Are you using Anaconda/Spyder?

Comment: no, im using Python's IDLE

Comment: Found the same issues when running your code. I updated my answers with steps to have pytesseract working without the raise TesseractNotFoundError()

Answer (score 0):

It seems pytesseract is not installed.

Try it:

```
import importlib.util
print(importlib.util.find_spec('ytesseract'))
```

If it's not installed you will get: None

If you have it, it will show the directory, this is me, asking if I have pandas:

```
ModuleSpec(name='pandas', loader=<_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x03E66F90>, origin='C:\\Users\\XXX\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32\\lib\\site-packages\\pandas\\__init__.py', submodule_search_locations=['C:\\Users\\XXX\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32\\lib\\site-packages\\pandas'])
```

pytesseract requires tessaract and tessaract-ocr, for tesseract:

```
pip install tesseract
```

For tessaract-ocr:

```
 https://github.com/UB-Mannheim/tesseract/wiki
```

Execute the installation. Mine was installed in 'C:/Program Files/'

Then I've pasted it in my Pytho developing interface:

```
  pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:/Program Files/Tesseract-OCR/tesseract'
```

I executed your code:

```
  text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img, config='')
```

And the print returned:

```
  Detected Number is: 7
```

It's not the output expected, but at least the "pytesseract.pytesseract.TesseractNotFoundError:" is gone.

Comment: for some reason I cant find pytesseract on my pc, when I go to search and type 'pytesseract', it says not found

Comment: The pytesseract is inside python folder, you printed that when I asked you for the import importlib.util/print(importlib.util.find_spec('pytesseract')) . But the tesseract-ocr must be downloaded from here "https://github.com/UB-Mannheim/tesseract/wiki" and installed. After installation you will see it somewhere in your pc.